# How can I move the activecell to whatever the function parameter is?

Tags: excel, vba

How can I move the activecell? Specifically, if put in cell C37 "=stringOfCells(C26)", instead of returning $C$26 it is returning $C$39.

```
Function StringOfCells(R As Range)

    R.Select
    MsgBox ActiveCell.Address

End Function
```

Comment: Executing a **UDF** in a worksheet cell cannot change *Selection,* you would need a sub to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't select a different cell inside of a UDF that is called from an excel formula. The only cell you can effect is the cell that is doing the calling, and that is only through the return of the function. This is a limitation of UDF's.

If you are just trying to get the Address of the cell that you input as a range to the UDF, then don't bother with selecting and activating. Instead just:

```
Function StringOfCells(R As Range)

     StringOfCells(R.Address)

End Function
```